# changing image to gif after event

Tags: c#, winforms

i have created a game, and im trying to get the image of the enemies once they have been shot to chnage to a explosion gif before they dissapear but i cant seem to get it to work, you can see the code below where it is meant to change to gif but when you pay the gamethe nemies just dissapear without the gif showing

```
 lasers.RemoveAll(laser => laser.isDisposed);
            foreach (Laser laser in lasers)
            {
                laser.MoveLaser(this);
                foreach (Invader ship in invaders)
                {
                    if (laser.laser.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ship.ship.Bounds))
                    {
                        laser.isDisposed = true;
                        laser.laser.Dispose();
                        ship.ship.Image = SpaceInvaders.Properties.Resources.explosionGIF1;
                        ship.isDisposed = true;
                        ship.ship.Dispose();
                        score = score + 2; //adds 2 points to players score if enemy is hit
                        lblScore.Text = score.ToString(); //updates the score label
```

Comment: Well, you set an Image to the property of an object, then dispose of the object that should show it. Btw, don't try to set `[object].isDisposed = true;`, it's read-only. Just dispose of an object when needed. Btw2, you need to assign `Properties.Resources.[Some Image]` to a reusable Image object: right now you're generating a new Image each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jimi explained

> Well, you set an Image to the property of an object, then dispose of the object that should show it. Btw, don't try to set [object].isDisposed = true;, it's read-only. Just dipose of an object when needed. Btw2, you need to assign Properties.Resources.[Some Image] to a reusable Image object: right now you're generating a new Image each time.

You're disposing the ship and with that the image.
An example solution would be to create a new GIF object that self-disposes after it has been played once. When the ship is destroyed, a new GIF object is created in the same place the ship was.

Comment: im not sure how i would do that? would i need to create a gif classthen after disposing of the enemy enable the gif class?

Comment: Yes, a new class for the gif